# Customers credit system, oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, credits

I am an oversea student, so I am not familiar with "Credit System" but I have a database question which is related to it. I just could not understand it well.

Here it the question:

Write a query:
*The billing officer would like to know which customers are currently over their credit limit.*

The schema of database is:

```
Sales_Rep (SLSRep_Number [pk], Last, First, Street, City, State, Post_Code,
Total_Commission, Commission_Rate)
Customer (Customer_Number [pk], Last, First, Street, City, State, Post_Code,
Balance, Credit_Limit, SLSRep_Number [fk])
Orders (Order_Number [pk], Order_Date, Customer_Number [fk])
Part (Part_Number [pk], Part_Description, Units_on_Hand, Item_Class, Warehouse_Number, Unit_Price)
Order_Line (Order_Number, [pk1] Part_Number [pk2], Number_Ordered, Quoted_Price)
```

Any idea?

Is that just :

```
Select customer_number,last,first,balance,credit_limit
from customer
where balance > credit_limit;
```

or might be:

```
select * from
    (select mytable.customer_number,sum(mytable.number_ordered*mytable.quoted_price) as customer_cost from
        (select customer.customer_number,order_line.number_ordered,order_line.quoted_price
        from customer,orders,order_line
        where customer.customer_number = orders.customer_number
        and orders.order_number = order_line.order_number) mytable
    group by mytable.customer_number) mytable2,customer
where customer.credit_limit < mytable2.customer_cost
and customer.customer_number = mytable2.customer_number;
```

Comment: I don't think it was poor English, so removed your comment. ;)

Answer (score 0):

first query is right, It will give the customer who has balance beyond the credit limit.

Comment: assuming `Balance` is holds the amount to compare with the customer's credit limit.